# How to change the seller_fee_basis_points using metaboss?

Tags: metadata, solana, metaplex

I want to change the value of the seller_fee_basis_points in the metadata of a solana blockchain NFT.

In the metaboss documentation I do not see a call method for updating the seller fee.

To change the name the command would be used:
 `metaboss update name --keypair <PATH_TO_KEYPAIR> --account <MINT_ACCOUNT> --new-name <NEW_NAME>`

But how can one change the seller_fee_basis_points in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s easy. Just use the [metaboss update data or data-all](https://metaboss.rs/update.html#update-data-all) command.

I would do the following process:

1. run [metaboss decode](https://metaboss.rs/decode.html) -o  --full --list-file .json (if you don’t have a hashlist run metaboss snapshot mints)
2. Use search and replace in the folder where the json files went to to modify the seller_fee_basis_points accordingly
   3.run [metaboss update-all](https://metaboss.rs/update.html#update-data-all)

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

is there a way to set royalties fee based on the listing price?
just for ex:
-list price below 1sol set fee at 8%
-list price above 1sol set fee at 5%

Or is it doable on ME? I don't want do to it manually as it wouldn't be sustainable.

Open to suggestions :)
Thanks

Comment: These are follow-up questions, and should be asked as a new question (or maybe in the comments to an already submitted answer, if applicable); not submitted as an answer to a different question.